# in assets:precompile getting following error in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, production, ruby-on-rails-4.1

In rails 4 during rake asset:precompile in production mode I am getting following error.
i am running : 
rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production

Error : 
[image]

Searched in application.css file but everything looks clean. I am not sure where I am missing those symbols. any way to check in which file exactly  I am missing this ?

This is my complete application.css file :

```
/*
 * This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.css, which will include all the files
 * listed below.
 *
 * Any CSS and SCSS file within this directory, lib/assets/stylesheets, vendor/assets/stylesheets,
 * or vendor/assets/stylesheets of plugins, if any, can be referenced here using a relative path.
 *
 * You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at the top of the
 * compiled file, but it's generally better to create a new file per style scope.
 *
 *= require social-share-button
 *= require jquery.tagsinput
 *= require_tree .
 *= require_self
*/


.blog_post{
    margin-left: 5%;
    width: 75%;
}

.blog_component{
    margin-top: 2%;
}

.entry-title{ 

}
.post_title{

    color: #000000;
    font-family: cursivefont;
    font-size: 52px;
    height: 119%;
    line-height: 155%;
    margin-left: 20%;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    width: 60%;
}

.left_content{
    width: 50%;
    margin-left: 10%;
    font-family: roboto_normal;
    /*margin-top: 5%;*/
    float:left;
}

.right_content{
     border: 1px solid;
    float: right;
    margin-right: 10%;
    padding: 2%;
    width: 20%;
    /*font-family: roboto_normal;*/

}

.right_content > .recent_post {
    /* font-family: roboto_normal;
    font-size: 195%;
    font-weight: bold;*/
    font-family: roboto_normal;
    font-size: 190%;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 0 8% 8%;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.footer_section{
    float: left;
    width: 70%;
}

@font-face
{
font-family: cursivefont;
src: url(Antonio-Bold.ttf);
}

@font-face{
    font-family: roboto_normal;
    src: url(RobotoCondensed-Light.ttf);
}

*::selection {
  background: #cc0000;
  color: #ffffff;
}
*::-moz-selection {

  background: #000000;
  color: #ffff00;
}
*::-webkit-selection {

  background: #cc0000;
  color: #ffffff;
}


.comment-section{

    margin-left: 15%;
}

.complete_comment{
    background-color: #F8F8F8;
    border: 1px dashed;
    margin: 2%;
    padding: 3%;
}
.user-comment{
    font-family: roboto_normal;
    margin: 30px 8px 8px;
    padding: 1px;
    width: 80%;
}

.commenter {

    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 18px;
    margin-left: 2%;
    text-decoration: underline;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}


.comment{
    margin-left: 5%;
    font-size: 16px;
}

.test{
    padding: 10%;

}

#error{
    padding: 10%;
}
```

Comment: Post your application.css file

Comment: it's too long.. not fit for this text field. where Can I share ?

Comment: Posted, check now @BSpiros

Comment: I can't find the error at first glance, but I will recommend that you clean up your code. Take a look at http://mdo.github.io/code-guide/#css-syntax

Answer (score 0):

Try `rake assets:clean`, and then try the precompile again. Where are you trying to push this to btw?

Comment: pushing to amazon ec2.. in the local also if I will run in production mode it's giving the same error. please help. I am in terrible problem.

Comment: Any way to identify exactly in which file it's having the error, I think all files are together considered as application.css file..  ?

Comment: Maybe remove them one at a time and try compiling? Also, maybe faster, maybe try a search for left and right brackets in each .css file and check for mismatching numbers?

Answer (score 0):

Best way to fix this kind of css issue. 
Validate your css files here and it'll list all syntax errors.

http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/validator

It fixed my issue, had missing syntax.